# Is it possible to swap out a set of lists for an array of those lists in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I was looking at this code from [Google Charts' website](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines):

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Diameter', 'Age'],
           [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

       var options = {
         title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
         hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
         vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
         legend: 'none',
         trendlines: { 0: {} }    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
       };

       var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
       chart.draw(data, options);
    }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='polynomial2_div' style='width: 900px; height: 500px;'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and I was wondering if it would be possible to take the lists inside the data variable (that is: [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52]...), store them into an array before calling var data, and then replace the lists with the array?
So something like this:

```
function drawChart() {
  var array = [[8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Diameter', 'Age'],
        array]);
```

What I did above doesn't work of course, but I wanted to know if the concept was doable. Is there another way for the function to read lists from the array?

Comment: Using es6, `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Diameter', 'Age'],
        ...array]);`

Comment: Oh cool! That was so simple haha. Thank you! =)

Comment: Please don't use titles such as "is it possible". Almost anything is possible. In the worst case, you will get short answers saying "yes, it's possible". If you mean "how to do X", then say that.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you the advice! I'll be sure to not make that mistake again!